# There's a issue with video's fast-forwarding and rewind in flash mode.

Tags: flash, jwplayer, pseudo-streaming

Pseudo-streaming works fine, but after rewinding the timescale bar goes back to the beginning and time starts counting from 0:00.
For example, if you click on 01:00 minute mark, the video starts playing from 01:00, but the timescale shows 0:00.

Comment: You need to do better than this above desciption. How does your pseudo-streaming solution work? Does it involve PHP or is it server range- requests? Is there a server generating the video (ie: packaging later frames as a new video so that it plays from 00:00 onwards)?. Basically, how can we recreate your issue? Most formats like FLV or MP4 have timestamps for frames so it should be correct if read via `netstream.time` in the Flash code.

Comment: We use start parameter on url of mp4 video. `http://path.to/file.mp4?start=90`

Comment: What kind of server you got? Is it NGINX? Anyways putting a `start=90` is not normal way to access a video and so is a specific feature of your server. Basically if you're providing `90` (seconds?) and serving that as start of video going onwards, you can imagine the player assumes what it gets is frame 1 going onwards (it doesnt know the picture if 90 seconds onwards) so to fix either change the JW Player code to account for the offset (It's a generic "normal usage" tool and was not designed for your situation, you have to edit its code & recompile a new SWF). Do you have test link to show?

Comment: PS: I meant can u provide a test video stream link... I want to make a test app checking if correct time can be shown from accounting for offset in link `http://path.to/file.mp4?start=90`. Might be easier to then explain how you can update the JW Player code yourself (where, how, etc)...

Comment: @VC.One thanks for you trying, but official jwplayer support confirmed - pseudo streaming not supported for jw7 player. [my question](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16340911-jwplayer-7-flash-pseudo-streaming-problem-on-seek)

Answer (score 0):

JW Player 7 does not support pseudostreaming. Which version are you using?

Comment: Latest version 7.44

Comment: @HeidiWF, does JW Player use `netstream.time` to check the video timestamps? If yes, then the Asker must be doing something else causing an issue of this **time reseting**.